# Efficient way of replacing the word in string from array having same prefixes in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like these:

```
abc pvt ltd
abc pvt. ltd
abc private ltd
abc pvt limited and so on
```

I want all the combination for string from any of above string by using an array like these:

```
["pvt","pvt.","private"]
["ltd","ltd.","limited"]
```

As the prefixes are same for same. How to return the array of all the string combinations?

Comment: @pr1nc3 but its not working

Comment: Doesn't matter :)  just saw us your effort and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your snippet, please see inline explanation

```
$temp = [];
$temp = array_map(function($val){ // exploding by space
    return explode(" ", $val);
}, $arr);

$transposed = array_map(null, ...$temp); // merging same indexes
$transposed = array_map(function($item){ // making unique values
    return array_unique($item);
},$transposed);
array_shift($transposed); // remove first index
print_r($transposed);die;
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37ac918451a1c82f208a250ca99dcddd866d8731).

Answer (score 1):

First use explode() to convert your string into an array (on space character):

```
<?php $string = "string with double string values";
$array = explode(" ", $string);
// result: ["string","with","double","string","values"]
```

Then use array_unique() to filter unique results:

```
<?php array_unique($array)
// result: ["string","with","double","values"]
```